# onChange does not work for DateTimePicker in Struts 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, struts2, struts2-jquery

I have the following piece of code :

```jsp
<sx:datetimepicker name="dateOfBirth" id="dateOfBirth"
displayWeeks="5" displayFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" onchange="test()"/>
```

But for this the `onChange` event does not work, although I have a simple javascript function like this:

```jsp
<script>
function test(){
    alert('hi-----');
}
</script>
```

**Note:** I read somewhere that it is a bug in Struts that the `onChange` event doesn't work for DateTimePicker. However I am not sure about it. Is there any workaround discovered for it?

Comment: Use topics. These are (old, deprecated) tags, and they're not the same as plain HTML DOM elements. They're (old, deprecated) Dojo widgets. You should not be using these.

Answer (score 0):

Dojo tags are deprecated. Use jQuery tags. You can find more about [struts2-jquery-plugin](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery). You should use [datepicker tag](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/wiki/DatePickerTag).

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags" %>
<head>
  <link href="<s:url value="/css/template_styles.css"/>" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <sj:head jqueryui="true" />
  <title></title>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.subscribe('changeTopic', function(event,data) {
    alert('Date : '+event.originalEvent.dateText);
});
</script>  
<sj:datepicker name="dateOfBirth" id="dateOfBirth" label="DOB" displayFormat="dd/MM/yy" onChangeTopics="changeTopic"/>
```

Comment: could you please tell me what taglib to use for datepicker? and also do i need to install any jar for it? (NOTE: i tried to use onChangeTopics for datetimepicker, but it did not work)

Comment: the plugin download from the link posted.