# How to calculate the Age after selecting date of birth

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery

I followed this link below to calculate age based on the date of birth selection

[Getting age automatically when given Date of Birth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151480/getting-age-automatically-when-given-date-of-birth)

but I am not able to calculate the date in the age field

I have used struts2-jquery-plugin-3.7.1.jar.

```jsp
<sj:datepicker id="dob" name="dateOfBirth" label="Change Month and Year" changeMonth="true" changeYear="true" displayFormat ="dd-mm-yy"></sj:datepicker>    

<s:textfield class="w3-input w3-border" placeholder="Age" name="age" id="age"/>
```

and the script which I used is :

```jsp
<script>
    $('#dob').datepicker({
        onSelect: function(value, ui) {
            var today = new Date(),
                dob = new Date(value),
                age = new Date(today - dob).getFullYear() - 1970;

            $('#age').text(age);
        },
        maxDate: '+0d',
        yearRange: '1920:2010',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
</script>
```

Even I am not able to scroll through a list of years available, I am only getting a 10 years list (I want a scrollable year from 1990 to till 2016 that is the current year)

Where I am getting wrong? I am stuck with this and don't know the other solution to calculate the age!

Answer (score 0):

The struts2-jquery plugin is using tags to render its own datepicker based on jquery ui added via plugin. You are messing a datetepicker bound to the same element. You should use either plugins' datepicker or native datepicker but not both.

To specify years range from 1990 till 2016 you can use option  `yearRange: '1900:2016'`. [This is the reference from jQuery API](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange).

If you want to use plugins' version of datepicker then you should refer [Date Picker Tag Wiki Page](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/wiki/DatePickerTag).

<kbd>[JSFiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/gkz5basL/1/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks alot sir, as now I am able to selct a range of year by using yearRange attritbute of struts2 jquery plugin, but still I am not able to calculate the age on selection of the date from sj datepicker, on which event of it I am going to call the above script??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25159250/onchange-does-not-work-for-datetimepicker-in-struts2                                                    Following your this link  I call the function to calculate the age as soon as the user selects the date  ' $.subscribe('changeTopic', function(event,data) {
        var today = new Date(),
                                dob = event.originalEvent.dateText,
                                age = new Date(today - dob).getFullYear() - 1970,
        alert('age : ');
                            $('#age').text(age);
                            });'

Comment: The JSFiddle is for native datepicker, how Can I implement it using the struts2 jquery datepicker(with sj tags?)?

Comment: Where you going wrong? - `how Can I implement it using the struts2 jquery datepicker`

Comment: I am not getting how to call function to calculate age using struts2 jquery plugin tag..

Comment: In JSFiddle the function is called on select event, and don't use struts2 jquery plugin if you can't.

Comment: Sir, I want to know how can I call function using using the sj tag? As I want to learn that.

Comment: you can change it in the subscribed topic, just use jquery selector to set the value. Please upvote links that helped you.